# Parsing Json; Write data to the TreeView branch

Tags: c#, json, winforms, parsing, treeview

I have a large [json](/questions/tagged/json) file, in which the data is arranged like this:

- **id** - item id
- **parent** - parent id
- **name** - name

  ...
  {
  id: "2859",
  parent: "5853",
  name: "Moscow"
  },
  ...

I need to throw it in TreeView.
Help please = (

Now I do it this way:

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

        foreach (var _data in data.data)
        {
            bool find = false;

            foreach(TreeNode n in Regions.Nodes)
            {
                if (n.Name == _data.parent)
                {
                    bool find2 = false;
                    n.Nodes.Add(_data.id, _data.name);
                    find = true;
                }
            }

            if (find != true)
            {
                Regions.Nodes.Add(_data.id, _data.name);
            }

        }
```

[Json File](https://www.bicotender.ru/ajax/regiontree/)

Comment: Can you clarify that the JSON structure is actually flat though? Is there any possibility that an entry early in the file could refer to the ID of a node that is defined later?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work correctly for two reasons:

1. You assume that if an item has a parent, that parent will come first in the data, and therefore it will have been added to the tree when you try to find it.  However, this does not hold true.  If you follow the chain of ids in the data, there are cases for which the parent item appears *after* the child.
2. You do not handle the case where an item's parent is not at the root level. 
   If an item's parent was previously added to the tree as a child of a root level node, then it will not be found in the root node list, so you will end up adding the item to the root instead of to the correct parent.

What you need to do is process the data in two passes using a dictionary lookup:

First, create all the individual `TreeNodes` from the data and add them to a dictionary, keyed by ID.
Then, iterate over the data a second time, and for each item, look up the corresponding node and its parent node in the dictionary using their respective IDs.  If the parent is found, add the node to the parent's node list, otherwise add it to the root node list.

Here is what it would look like in code:

```
void PopulateTreeViewFromJson(TreeView treeView, string json)
{
    RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    var dict = root.data.ToDictionary(n => n.id, 
        n => new TreeNode(n.name.Trim()) { Name = n.id });

    foreach (var item in root.data)
    {
        TreeNode node = dict[item.id];
        TreeNode parentNode;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(item.parent, out parentNode))
        {
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
        else
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```